# Writing a complex namespace xml with vba

Tags: xml, excel, vba

So...another xml namespace question.  I want to write this namespace with vba

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Datas xsi:schemaLocation="uri:rhubarb:pie RHUBARB%20PIE%202012.xsd" xmlns="uri:rhubarb:pie" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<\Datas>
```

and here is my code so far

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Create_Database()

'Declare document objects
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim xRoot As IXMLDOMElement

'create new DOMDocument
Set xDoc = New DOMDocument60

'Create processing instructions
Set xNode = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding= 'UTF-8'")
Set xNode = xDoc.InsertBefore(xNode, xDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0))

'create root element
Set xRoot = xDoc.createElement("Datas")
xDoc.appendChild xRoot
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xsi:schemaLocation", "uri:rhubarb:pie RHUBARB%20PIE%202012.xsd"
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns", "uri:rhubarb:pie"
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

'save xml file
xDoc.Save "C:\Users\danny\Desktop\xml\Database.xml"
'clear xDoc from memory
Set xDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

...but I know in writing the namespace I have too many arguments.  The only thing I can find online would be to write my namespace like this:

```
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

I keep getting an error about too many arguments.  My question:  How do I write a more complex namespace?  Or is that even a correct way to go about writing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries I've figured it out.  Ill edit it in case anyone else is looking for the same thing!

I changed this:

```
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xsi:schemaLocation", "uri:rhubarb:pie RHUBARB%20PIE%202012.xsd", "xmlns", "uri:rhubarb:pie", "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

To this:

```
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xsi:schemaLocation", "uri:rhubarb:pie RHUBARB%20PIE%202012.xsd"
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns", "uri:rhubarb:pie"
xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```